# How to check the path parameter in request using any static data file using Wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

I have created a stub to test an API say :http://localhost:8080/test/{customerName}

using [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock) as below:

```
wireMock.stubFor(get(urlPathMatching(/test/([A-Z0-9]{10})))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(OK).withBody("Hello World!"))
        );
```

I need to do two things:

1. Though [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock)provides header and query parameter checking but if i need to check or extract the path parameter Customer Name how i will do that?
2. If I extract the customer name anyhow then how i will check that this customer name is present in a particular data. (May be a big string,array or file contains the customer names).

I tried with extending [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock)->Custom Request Matchers but could not able to achieve any of the above mentioned.

In that first problem is you can't even create a stub using `stubFor(get(url...` You have to create by using the `stubFor(requestMatching..` with name of custom request matcher.

Comment: did you try http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/

Comment: Yes, i tried it as mentioned in last four lines of the query above.

Comment: Yes, i already tried it using extending wiremock as mentioned in last four lines of the query above . But I resolve this by urlPathMatching where I am checking the path parameter giving all the customer name in the string using the "I" (OR) equation. Though Custom Request matcher did not fit for my requirement . And reading form the file or connecting with DB is not the option in [tag:wiremock]

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `AbstractRegexPattern` to either capture path parameters or do additional tests on the path or do even both.

```
    final AtomicReference<String> urlField = new AtomicReference();
    final StringValuePattern urlPattern = new AbstractRegexPattern("/test/([A-Z0-9]{10})") {
        @Override
        public MatchResult match(final String url) {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                urlField.set(matcher.group(1));
            }

            // do additional verification on the URL if necessary
            // ..

            return super.match(url);
        }
    };
    wireMock.stubFor(get(new UrlPattern(urlPattern, true))
            .willReturn(ok().withBody("Hello World!"))
    );
```

After the test request the `urlField` will contain the matched URL field.

```
    // do the test request
    // ..

    System.out.println("URL field: " + urlField.get());
```

But, honestly, that feels like a workaround and not as viable as header or query parameter validation in WireMock.

---

Newer WireMock versions offer extensive request matching with `andMatching(ValueMatcher<Request>)`:

```
    final AtomicReference<String> urlField = new AtomicReference();
    wireMock.stubFor(get(urlMatching("/test/([A-Z0-9]{10})"))
            .andMatching(request -> {
                final String url = request.getUrl();
                final String customerName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                urlField.set(customerName);

                // do additional verification on the whole request if necessary
                // ..

                return MatchResult.exactMatch(); // or an error
            })
            .willReturn(ok().withBody("Hello World!"))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard functionality will be able to match the `customer` part of the URL and reuse it in the response. In the below JSON example this is implemented:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method" : "ANY",
        "urlPattern": "/test/([a-z]*)"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "Hello World: {{request.path.[1]}}",
        "transformers": ["response-template"]
    }
}
```

Sending a request: `http://localhost:8080/test/someclientname` will result in the following response: `Hello World: someclientname`.

It is possible to create a custom response template that uses the standard response template handlebars fuctionality to parse the parameters and use that information to fetch a specific file, or when not available a generic one. In high level this idea is desribed in a [WireMock Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wiremock-user/lLhUB-yBY6Q).

Comment: Thats not my question

Comment: The original answer was aimed for part 1. The second part to your question will be a custom development.